# Where do Google Cloud Platform questions belong?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

In the [google-cloud-platform](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-platform) tag wiki is the following statement:

> Cloud computing platform offered by Google. Online Google applications and platforms are off-topic here and should be asked on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.

In the meta post:
[Where do EC2 and AWS questions truly belong?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11991/where-do-ec2-and-aws-questions-truly-belong)
, I addressed the concern that these types of hosting/administration questions do not belong on Web Applications.  The same holds for Google Cloud Platform.  While GMail, Google Sheets, Google Docs *are* on topic on Web Applications, we are receiving questions that have to do with Linux shell access, etc., which are more appropriate for Super User.

I have pointed this out to a moderator in the past, and questions continued to be migrated over.  I proposed to that moderator that the tag wiki should be changed, and attempted to [make the change myself](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/874525), but (and rightly so) it was pointed out that perhaps a meta discussion was in order.

I would like to submit for consideration that this portion of the tag wiki be removed so that these questions are no longer migrated in error.  If these questions truly don't belong on Super User, the tag wiki should point to where they do belong.

Comment: I can't lay my hands on the Meta question, but I recall this being addressed in another question besides the one you linked.  The gist of the answer was that if the question concerns the cloud platform as a hardware resource extension of your computer and is about the application running there that would be on-topic if you were running it locally on the PC,  it's generally on topic at SU.  Questions about dealing with the cloud platform, itself, are off-topic here.  (cont'd)

Comment: But where does it belong if it's off-topic here is the complex mess described in allquixotic's answer in your link.  The [amazon-ec2] tag wiki excerpt contains "Web service questions are on topic here only if the question is about the operating system or using a PC application hosted there".  Would it be appropriate to add similar wording to the [google-cloud-platform] wiki?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there needs to be one more technical SE site created for this. Something like cloudops.stackexchange.com (Cloud Operations) for AWS, Google Cloud Platform and Azure questions that pertain to the technologies that are *specific* to those platforms.

For now, ServerFault *could possibly* be acceptable, but don't take my word for it -- ask them.

Comment: Yeah, migrations to Server Fault can be problematic.  I was burned once on one a long time ago, so I tend to just not vote that way.  I do agree that these questions need a home, but Area 51 has tightened its requirements as of late, so I don't know how well a proposal would go over.

Comment: Well, knowing is better than not knowing, right? Here's how that proposal would go over: Badly. It got closed. https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122431/cloud-operations So I guess you just ask/migrate those questions on StackOverflow or ServerFault and hope for the best.

Comment: there is [devops.se] Stack Exchange