# Would asking a question about Power Automate be on topic here?

Tags: discussion

The title explains it fairly well. Would asking a question about Power Automate be on topic here?

Comment: Further to my answer below, also see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11991/where-do-ec2-and-aws-questions-truly-belong

Comment: @Mokubai I asked my question here because I thought it would be more on topic there. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Read-email-then-get-task/m-p/701484#M58195

Comment: Power Automate is a low code solution; I would recommend asking them on Stack Overflow over Superuser.

Answer (score 1):

From [What is Microsoft Power Automate (Previously Known As Microsoft Flow)?](https://perfect-image.co.uk/business-applications/microsoft-power-platform/power-automate/)

> Microsoft Power Automate is a **cloud-based service that enables users to create and automate processes** and actions that save a lot of time and effort with repetitive tasks.

(Emphasis mine)

Cloud computing problems are only on topic where they overlap with programs or problems that occur on a machine you personally control. Many of our tags [regarding cloud services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/azure) include wording along the lines of

> Questions about web service questions are on topic here only if the question is about the operating system or using a PC application hosted there. Otherwise, other sites on the network may be more appropriate.

So largely all we can say is that it depends on the focus of your question. If it is about driving the web interface then probably [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) may be better. Otherwise you may have to find a [more specialised site](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology).